# binomial coefficient using one dimensional array

Tags: c++

hey i want to implement algorithm of binomial coefficient using one dimensional array in C.can anyone help me.
 Thanks...

Comment: We will not do it for you, but help you do it yourself. You can start by posting the code you wrote for the 2D version.

Answer (score 1):

Simply construct the [pascal triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) line by line.

Comment: how? please help me in coding. i have done it in 2 dimensional array

Comment: Consider the fact that you need just the *last* line to compute the next one. Thus, you should be able to discard the previous lines. You will have to update the items of your array accordingly.